# Using Twitter API in react-native app

Tags: android, ios, api, twitter, react-native

Being very new to using the twitter API, I am facing trouble while retrieving all tweet feeds for an account in my app using list view as shown in the screenshot below.

I've read various documentation but couldn't find any good material, also went through Twitter documentation https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/player/approval but still facing trouble in using this API for react-native app.

Please suggest some good examples how I can achieve this.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrOW3.png)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve/do?

Comment: By "achieving all tweet feeds for an account" do you mean you are trying to retrieve all tweets for a specific Twitter account?

Comment: Yes petar, am trying to retrieve all tweets for a specific account.

Comment: Similar to something on this blog https://blog.twitter.com/2016/doing-more-with-140-characters in the top left section "Tweets by twitterdev"

Comment: @Pragyajha Were you able to achieve this? Please let us know how.